# when Template file is called from another Template file product details are unable to show: In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, template

When I am Trying to call Custom Template file test.phtml on product view page Template file i.e on  wrapper.phtml template file is called but, when I am trying to output product details from my custom  test.phtml I am unable to output,So any help how to get product details  on my Custom test.phtml

File path:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml

<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/test.phtml')) ?>
```

My Custom Template File Path:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/test.phtml
```

But I was unable to load product details when I write code on test.phtml file

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to forum.Add more information about what we tried, whats your magento version and some code part

Comment: In Magento 2 version

Comment: How you are trying to load product ??? can you explain

Comment: $productId = 8;
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);echo $currentproduct->getName();                                                                                when i am adding this in test.phtml, i was getting output,                                                                       but when i try to put $_option = $block->getOption();                                                                    these lines and try to get details i am unable to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
$objectManagerProduct = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$objectManagerProduct->create('\Magento\Framework\Registry');

$category = $objectManagerProduct->registry('current_product');

productId = $category->getId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$currentproduct =
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loa&#8204;&#8203;d($productId);

echo $currentproduct->getName();
```